# Google Maps API - Autocomplete UK County

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm using the Google address auto complete API to format addresses for an internal app using the standard sample code Google provides at:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/places-autocomplete-addressform

I correctly get a response similar to the below for each post code:

```
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "BA1 1UN",
            "short_name" : "BA1 1UN",
            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Bath",
            "short_name" : "Bath",
            "types" : [ "postal_town" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Bath and North East Somerset",
            "short_name" : "Bath and North East Somerset",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "England",
            "short_name" : "England",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "United Kingdom",
            "short_name" : "GB",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         }
```

And all my form fields complete fine except except for the "administrative_area_level_2" one i.e. the county.  My working HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Postal Town</label>
    <input class="form-control field" placeholder="Enter your country" 
    required="true" name="postal_town" id="postal_town">
    <p class="help-block">Enter your country.</p>
</div>
```

But this does not:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>County</label>
    <input class="form-control field" placeholder="Enter your county" required="true" name="administrative_area_level_2" id="administrative_area_level_2">
    <p class="help-block">Enter your county.</p>
</div>
```

How can I access that field to auto complete the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it's nice to walk away and have fresh eyes.  Pretty easy fix, the standard Google autocomplete has the following code:

```
          var placeSearch, autocomplete;
          var componentForm = {
            street_number: 'short_name',
            route: 'long_name',
            postal_town: 'long_name',
            administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
            country: 'long_name',
            postal_code: 'short_name'
          };
```

You just have to include the additional field so the code reads:

```
          var placeSearch, autocomplete;
          var componentForm = {
            street_number: 'short_name',
            route: 'long_name',
            postal_town: 'long_name',
            administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
            administrative_area_level_2: 'short_name',
            country: 'long_name',
            postal_code: 'short_name'
          };
```

Now it populates the form automatically, I haven't tried but assume it applies to the other fields as well.  Love Google!